# Classic asp export to excel (with parameter)

Tags: excel, asp-classic

I am using the education iSAMS software to produce a report, then export that data to Excel. Almost everything is written in Classic ASP, and it's a 2-frame window, containing Student IDs on the left frame, and a report for each student ID on the right frame. Click on a student of the left, and the report shows in the right pane.

The report uses the Student ID as a parameter :

```
paramBuilder.NextParameter(intID)
```

... and this works fine and produces the report from the SQL loop.

However, I'm unable to use the parameter in the Excel export part (I get the error "syntax error or access violation"). If I remove the parameter from the WHERE clause, the export works (although it exports all Student IDs, not just the one).

I've tried just about everything I can think of, but I still hit a brick wall. Is it possible to re-use this parameter in the export?

Thanks in advance.

Here is the code :

```
<!--#include file="../../system/includes/inc_security.asp"-->
<!--#include file="../../system/includes/inc_theme.asp"-->

<% 'viewstudent-test.asp-v111-11-09-2017 --Includes Export to Excel

'txtModule="iSAMS_SCHOOLDIRECTORY"
'txtContext="SDSTUDENT"

intID = request.querystring("id")
%>

<!--- SHOW THE SUBJECT REPORTS --->
<table border="1px" width="100%">
<tr>
 <td>Subject</td>
 <td>Subject Report</td>
</tr>

<% 
sql = "SELECT DISTINCT txtSchoolID, txtID, txtCommentID, txtComment FROM CAN_Tbl_UCAS_Reports WHERE intReportType = 1 AND txtSchoolID = " & paramBuilder.NextParameter(intID) & " ORDER BY txtID"

Set rsRecord = Database.GetRs(sql, conn, paramBuilder.Parameters)
 if not rsRecord.EOF then
  do until rsRecord.EOF
 ' First we need to create our Variables
   SchoolID = rsRecord("txtSchoolID")
   ConID = rsRecord("txtCommentID")
   Com = rsRecord("txtComment")
%>
<tr>
<td style="text-align:center; vertical-align:top; height:10px"><%Response.Write(rsRecord.Fields("txtID").value)%></td>
<td style="text-align:center">
  <form action="updateform.asp" method="post">
   <input type="hidden" name="ID" value="<%=ConID%>" />
   <input type="hidden" name="SchoolID" value="<%=SchoolID%>" /> 
    <textarea rows="3" cols="180" name="comment"><%=Com%></textarea>
  </form>
<td>
</tr>
<%
 rsRecord.Movenext 
  loop
   end if
    rsRecord.close
     set rsRecord = nothing 
%>
</table>

<%If Request("ACT")="xls" Then
'Build & Execute Your SQL Command
 SQL = "SELECT DISTINCT txtSchoolID, txtID, SubjectTeacher, txtComment FROM  CAN_Tbl_UCAS_Reports WHERE intReportType = 1 AND txtSchoolID = '" &  intID & "' ORDER BY txtID"

  Set rstSearch = conn.Execute(SQL)
  'Set the HTTP Header
  Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel"
  Response.AddHeader "Content-Disposition", "filename=""Excel Export.xls"""

'Output Table %>

<table border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="5">
 <tr>
  <th>Header 1</th><th>Header 2</th><th>Header 3</th>
 </tr><% Do While Not rstSearch.EOF %>
 <tr>
  <td><%=rstSearch(1)%></td><td><%=rstSearch(3)%></td>
</tr>
<% rstSearch.MoveNext : Loop %>
</table>
<%
'Stop Processing Page Now
  Response.End
   End If
%>

<form action="?" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="ACT" value="xls">
<input type="submit" value="Export To Excel">
</form>

</body>

</html>
<!--#include file="../../system/connections/inc_dbconnclose.asp"-->
```

Comment: Are you sure the paramBuilder.NextParameter(intID) has the same value each time the method is called?

Comment: @Worksmarter - yes, it has the same value each time. There are some asp pages which contain several SQL loops with this parameter, and this always refers to the StudentID.

Comment: Do you get an error when the value is hard coded?

Comment: Response.write the SQL variable and confirm the query is what you expect.

Comment: Sorry, but I had missed out a bit of code when posting, and I've now added it in the section above, immediately above the "SHOW THE SUBJECT REPORTS".

It contains the line :

    `intID = request.querystring("id")`

When I do a Response.Write on intID, it shows the correct value, but it still does not get picked up in the SQL statement in the Export section, so I'm still doing something wrong.